# Intellij worksheet and classes defined in it

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm following along the Coursera course on functional programming in Scala and came along a weird behavior of the worksheet repl.

In the course a worksheet with the following code should give the following results on the right:

```
object rationals {
val x = new Rational(1, 2)              > x : Rational = Rational@<hash_code>
   x.numer                              > res0: Int = 1
   y. denom                             > res1: Int = 2
}

class Rational(x: Int, y: Int) {
   def numer = x
   def denom = y
}
```

What I get is

```
object rationals {                      > defined module rationals
val x = new Rational(1, 2)              
   x.numer                              
   y. denom                             
}

class Rational(x: Int, y: Int) {        > defined class Rational
   def numer = x
   def denom = y
}
```

Only after moving the `class` into the `object` I got the same result as in the code.

- Is this caused by Intellij, or have there been changes in Scala?
- Are there other ways around this?

Comment: This is IntelliJ worksheet behaviour which is very handy sometimes. Just write your `val`s and expressions outside the objects

Comment: @Odomontois Ok, it works. But I still don't see what's the point of his?

Comment: Some `val` definitions sometimes should not be evaluated in  the sequenced way. There could be complex dependencies between `lazy val`s or exceptions thrown at `.toString` stage because `object` is not full initialized yet. So in IDEA you could just wrap such nasty thing in objects, while in Eclipse you have no other options rather extract them in separate .scala source

Comment: @Odomontois If you want you could combine your comments into an answer. I would then accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the IntelliJ IDEA scala worksheet handles values inside the `objects` differently than Eclipse/Scala IDE.

Values inside objects are not evaluated in linear sequence mode, instead they are treated as normal scala object. You barely see information about it until explicit use.

To actually see your `val`s and expressions simply define or evaluate them outside any object\class

This behaviour could be a saviour in some cases. Suppose you have that definitions.

```
  val primes = 2l #:: Stream.from(3, 2).map(_.toLong).filter(isPrime)

  val isPrime: Long => Boolean = 
    n => primes.takeWhile(p => p * p <= n).forall(n % _ != 0)
```

Note that `isPrime` could be a simple `def`, but we choose to define it as `val` for some reason.

Such code is nice and working in any normal scala code, but will fail in the worksheet, because `val`s definitions are cross-referencing.

But it you wrap such lines inside some object like

```
object Primes {
  val primes = 2l #:: Stream.from(3, 2).map(_.toLong).filter(isPrime)

  val isPrime: Long => Boolean =
    n => primes.takeWhile(p => p * p <= n).forall(n % _ != 0)
}
```

It will be evaluated with no problem