# difficulty with scala package

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm working through the book Functional Programming in Scala and have run into difficulties. Here is the code:

```
package fpinscala.datastructures
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

object List {
  def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match {
    case Nil => 0
    case Cons(x,xs) => x + sum(xs)
  }
  def product(ds: List[Double]): Double = ds match {
    case Nil => 1.0
    case Cons(0.0, _) => 0.0
    case Cons(x,xs) => x * product(xs)
  }
  def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
  val example = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)))
  val example2 = List(1,2,3)
  val total = sum(example)
}
```

The code is from chapter 3 and is called "Listing 3.1 Singly-linked lists."

My problem is first, using a work sheet in IntelliJ, I get a warning message from the package statement telling me the package name doesn't correspond to the directories structure. The text book doesn't give any information about how to handle this. This is the first use of the package statement in the book and there is no discussion on "directories structure" anywhere.

My second problem is the code doesn't produce any "Res0" or anything at all on the right side where I expect to find something. Like total: Int 6 or something like that. Any pointers, advice?

Comment: although scala doesn't require correspondence between package names and sourcel directory structure, the java language does, so perhaps the works sheet assumes a java source tree.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is, the book refers to the worksheet of the *Eclipse IDE* not the one of *IntelliJ IDEA*. These are independent products, both have worksheets but [they work slightly differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33630274/intellij-worksheet-and-classes-defined-in-it).

In IntelliJ you wouldn't use packages at all (if I'm not mistaken). Also the contents of an `object` is not evaluated on the right-hand side. Instead, just move the stuff you want to evaluate (`example`, `example2`, `total`) to the top-level.

Unfortunately there is also some highlighting error due to the existence of `scala.Nil` and `scala.List` (from the standard library), although the worksheet correctly evaluates. I simply renamed them to `MyList` and `MyNil`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, and I'll mark your answer. You have solved the package question. I managed to reproduce the results you have provided here, except for the last line: val total=sum(example), which I have to comment out to get anything other than a blank page on the right side. The first four lines, defined trait... etc are fine and the results for example and example2 are fine. The middle lines, sum...  and product... don't appear and I get an error message, "not found: value sum" (or value product if I give that a try).   Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Note that I moved `sum` and `product` also to the top-level. Otherwise you would need to call `val total = MyList.sum(example)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I hadn't noted that until you pointed it our explicitly. You've done a lot to ease my frustrations.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is first, using a work sheet in IntelliJ, I get a warning
>   message from the package statement telling me the package name doesn't
>   correspond to the directories structure.

Create a directory called `fpinscala` and create another directory inside it called `datastructures` and put your class inside the second directory. Or you can ask from intellij to do that for you by pressing `Ctrl+Enter` on the warning message.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried both of your suggestions and neither were successful at removing the package warning.